# Ошибка ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Есть ajax запрос, после отправки которого постоянно вылазит ошибка

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#regForm').submit(function(e) {
        var frm = $('#regForm');
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {}
        var Form = this;

        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        });

        $.each(this, function(i, v) {
            var input = $(v);
            data[input.attr("path")] = input.val();
            delete data["undefined"];
        });
        $.ajax({
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type : frm.attr('method'),
            url : frm.attr('action'),
            dataType : 'json',
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error : function(data,status,er) {
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Вот метод который вызывается

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createNewUserAccount(
        @RequestBody RegistrationForm userForm) {
    try {
        userService.registerNewUserAccount(userForm);
    } catch (DuplicateEmailException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return "Error!";
    }
    return "Success!";
}
```

Но даже после успешного завершения метода, вылазит вот такая ошибка

```
data = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "Success!", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}, status = "parsererror", er = SyntaxError: Unexpected token S at Object.parse (native) at jQuery.extend.parseJSON (http://localhost:8080/static/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:550:23) at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:8080/static/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8429:19) at done (http://localhost:8080/static/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8185:15) at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.s.send.callback (http://localhost:8080/static/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8778:8) {message: "Unexpected token S"}
```

Comment: Ну так сервер возвращает не json, а в отправке запроса у вас зачем-то прописано ждать ответ json, вот и не работает

Comment: @Андрій Дзигар: Замените в dataType `json` на `text`, либо возвращайте json: `return '["Success!"]'`. Вообще, при успехе рекомендуется возращать user объект с allowed свойствами (REST-way). [Почитайте](http://jsonapi.org/).